# Can a problem with the case break on the dishwasher cause water from sink drainage to leak into dishwasher inlet?

Tags: dishwasher

Leakage of water through case brake into dishwasher. High loop installation without  garbage disposal. Poured food coloring in sink and had it leak into dishwasher at inlet, not up through drain. Is there some type of check valve failure that would cause this?

Comment: When you say "had it leak into dishwasher at inlet", could you instead describe **exactly** what happened? There is no connection between your sink drain and the potable water supply to your dishwasher, *none at all*.

Comment: Every time I run water in sink, and I open the dishwasher door I can see water leaking into the dishwasher from the left side of the dishwasher, which is where water comes in to fill DW. https://1drv.ms/u/s!AhZgHoG3VeKshKkodJb-2OnYL8-5mQ. Within a few hours of running water here and there at the sink, the bottom od DW is full of water and I have to turn dishwasher on to empty. Food coloring that I poured down sink drain can be seen inside the case break coming in on left side and traveling up the case and into the inlet. (with side metal panel removed to expose the case break.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out Samsung dishwasher has a case break on side of dishwasher where drain water routes through. In case of drain blockage or whatever it is by design that water would then reroute in this case break and reenter dishwasher through inlet on side of dishwasher wall. Though I had a high loop coming off of my piping, it was on a lateral pipe between dual bowl sink. I had to attach DW drain to one of the sink drains, followed by p trap. Water is now "not" backing up and filling entire drain hose that was causing pressure rerouting into dishwasher.